# DB2 Express V10.1 and db2cc binary

Tags: db2

I have just installed DB2 Express v10.1 with a personnalised installation where i have checked all composants but i can't find the db2cc binary to launch the control center.

someones know if db2cc binary has been renamed, deleted and how launch the control center ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DB2 Control Center was [deprecated](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0054250.html) starting in DB2 9.7.  IBM [discontinued](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0058731.html) it in DB2 10.1.

Control Center (and the other related tools) has been replaced by IBM Data Studio.  You can download Data Studio 3.1.1, the release that supports DB2 10.1 [from IBM](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032153).

Comment: sorry, i just do it, i didn't know how i can validate answer :)