# db2fs shows exception TypeError: netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined

Tags: db2, ubuntu-14.04

After successfully installing IBM DB2 Express V10.5_01 on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine I tried to follow the next step and start

```
db2fs
```

in an X-Windows session. I am asked to create a profile for firefox and a browser window comes up with an error message dialog showing

```
exception TypeError: netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined
```

When pressing ok for a few times the "create sample database" button disappears and instead a warning appears:

```
First Steps was unable to connect to the online DB2 Information Center and could not find an instance of a locally installed DB2 Information Center for this version of the product. To access product information, one of the following types of connections to a DB2 Information Center is required:

    Internet access to the online DB2 Information Center
    A locally installed version of the DB2 Information Center
    Access to a remotely configured DB2 Information Center
```

As a workaround I tried to use

```
db2sampl
```

after adding my user to the groups dasadm1 db2iadm1 and db2fadm1 that had been created by the installation procedure.

```
db2sampl -force

  Creating database "SAMPLE"...
  Existing "SAMPLE" database found...
  Dropping and recreating database "SAMPLE"...
  Attempt to drop existing database "SAMPLE" failed.
  Attempt to create the database "SAMPLE" failed.
  SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "SAMPLE  " could not be 
found.  SQLSTATE=42705


db2 list db directory
```

shows:

```
Database alias                       = SAMPLE
 Database name                        = SAMPLE
 Local database directory             = <path>/db2inst1
 Database release level               = 10.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = -1
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

unfortunately

```
db2cc
```

is not available anymore as an admin tool in V10.5 see [DB2 Express V10.1 and db2cc binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674887/db2-express-v10-1-and-db2cc-binary) and before downloading 
IBM Data Studio I'd first like to check the basic integrity of my installation.

```
db2help
```

e.g. gives the errormessage

```
/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -p
```

In all I have the feeling that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is not a properyly supported platform for IBM DB2 Express V10.5_01.

**How feasible is it to get IBM DB2 Express V10.5_01 running in this environment?**

Comment: What does `db2 list db directory` show?

Comment: I have the same problem with `db2fs` - according to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/936845 that PrivilegeManager ist no supported anymore since v17.    ----    Have you checked the integrity by logging in as _db2inst1_ user and running `db2val`? That worked for me, and I could use `db2sampl` and `db2`. (Same setup: v10.5 on 14.04)

Comment: please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it - I managed to get things running without db2fs along similar lines